# How to get accordion menu closed by default on load

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I have some jQuery code to make my lists act like an accordion. But the accordion is always open on page load. Can you please tell me how to close it on page load?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > li > a').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Please tell me how to edit it to keep the accordion closed on page load.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what your html code is, but if you want to hide that accordion content, I think you can do that with `$(window).load(function() {});`

- when the document has finished loading, you can hide the accordion content with a `hide()`, or `slideUp()` or whatever function (or maybe when the dom is ready?)
- (or if its possible. you could throw in some css to hide it, even though you didn't ask for it, I'm throwing it out there for the sake of it)

Check it out **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/msd1wner/1/)** or the snippet bellow:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
$(window).load(function() {
  //when the document finished loading, hide it; or maybe place this on the dom ready function?
  $('#nav li ul').hide();
});
```

```css
/*
#nav li ul{
    display: none
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Some accordion title I guess</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Some accordion content</li>
      <li>Some accordion content</li>
      <li>Some accordion content</li>
      <li>Some accordion content</li>
      <li>Some accordion content</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks a ton...no wonder people love these forums . Also the html code used is exactly what my css adapts to. thank you very much. ^_^ this code also remembers the last open menu.